# How to move backward parent folder

Tags: r, file

In R, I'm working on "./parent/Child/A". I want to move back parent folder "child", but when I type full path. It lost many times.

Comment: How exactly did you "type full path" and what do you mean "it lost many times?" Can you show some code?

Comment: Ok. I usually code like this: setwd("./parent/Child"). With short path as this example, it ok. But with long path, it's not good for me.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

```
setwd('..')
```

will move up one directory without entering the absolute path. Here's an example

```
> getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/D/Desktop/EDABaseball"
> setwd('..')
> getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/D/Desktop"
```

Answer (score 17):

I think you want to move back to the working directory `./parent/Child/`. This can be done in 2 ways, assuming your current working directory is `./parent/Child/A`

1) `setwd("..")`

2) `setwd("./..")`

3) `setwd("./parent/Child")`

Comment: what is the difference between using one or two dots? I had to go back two folders up and had to use 
"../../analisys/data"

Comment: @niklai to go back two levels in your directory hierarchy you'd enter the command `setwd("./../..")` and to move back three levels you'd enter the command `setwd("./../../..")` and so on.

Comment: Double quotes does not work in my Linux Mint. Single ones, do.

Answer (score 15):

I also find `dirname()` function pretty useful especially if your path is saved in a variable:

```
mypath <- getwd()

# The path of the parent directory:
dirname(mypath)
```

Comment: dirname is appropriate if one would like to just move one directly out of working directory. very useful. Thank you @HBat

Answer (score 4):

Moves up one directory in Linux

```
setwd("../")
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically I split the child folder using `strsplit` by `'/'` and then got the parent folder pasting the slices collapsing by `'/'`, except for the last one. I used `getwd()` to make the code reproducible, but you may use any folder.

```
myDir <- unlist(strsplit(getwd(), '/'))
paste0(myDir[-length(myDir)], collapse = '/')
```