# unzip a .zip file

Tags: r

I want to unzip a file in R. I completely don't know what to do.

I searched and I found it method like this :

```
unzip(zipfile, files = NULL, list = FALSE, overwrite = TRUE,
      junkpaths = FALSE, exdir = ".", unzip = "internal",
      setTimes = FALSE)
```

but I don't know what should I do with this.

Comment: possible dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053833/using-r-to-download-zipped-data-file-extract-and-import-data

Comment: @hrbrmstr - That one is for `unz()` though

Comment: the R documentation is really bad...

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
zipF<-file.choose() # lets you choose a file and save its file path in R (at least for windows)
outDir<-"C:\\Users\\Name\\Documents\\unzipfolder" # Define the folder where the zip file should be unzipped to 
unzip(zipF,exdir=outDir)  # unzip your file
```

Well you could also define both paths in R the classical way:

Assuming your zip file is named `file.zip`

```
zipF<- "C:\\path\\to\\my\\zipfile\\file.zip"
outDir<-"C:\\Users\\Name\\Documents\\unzipfolder"
unzip(zipF,exdir=outDir)
```

`exdir` defines the directory to extract files to. It will be created if not already available.
If you don't set `exdir`, `unzip` will just unzip it to your current working directory.

Comment: you can use forward slash in windows

Comment: How can I set the unzip method, so that unzipped files with the same name will be renamed. with WinZip that would be equivalent to "rename all".

Answer (score 3):

To unzip many files you can do also:

```
files <- list.files(path="../Output/datasets/", pattern=".zip$")
outDir <- "../Output/datasets/unzip"
for (i in files) {
  unzip(paste0("../Output/datasets/",i), exdir=outDir)
}
```

Where the [`../`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319168/how-to-move-backward-parent-folder) move up one directory without entering the absolute path.

And the unzip folder is created automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I did this

```
dataFrom="E:/test/"
folderTo="E:/test2/"
s=list.files(dataFrom)
j=1`enter code here`
while(j<=length(s))
{
  unzip(paste(dataFrom,s[j], sep=""),exdir=folderTo)
  j=j+1
}
```

Answer is: exdir doesn't exist, and it exists, I created