# unzipping .nc files from many BZIP folders in R

Tags: r, loops, unzip, bzip

I’m trying to extract .nc files from PowerArchiver **BZIP** in **R** from many different folders, would anyone be able to help me do this?

I have a code to extract and select the files but when I try and unzip using codes provided in previous stack overflow support (e.g. [unzip a .zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203800/unzip-a-zip-file)) I can’t find a code that works:

```
 < Warning message: In unzip(zipF, exdir = outDir) :
 error 1 in extracting from zip file>
```

Below is the R code I have to extract the files once out of the Zip files:

```
File <- dir("I:/Turbidity", include.dirs = FALSE, all.files = FALSE, recursive = TRUE)  # to select all files and not the file paths 

str(File) #21328 files 

FUllList <- NULL 
for(r_a_traiter in File){    
FileList <- NULL   
if(as.character(substr(r_a_traiter, 18,45))== as.character("-EUR-L4-SPIM-ATL-v01-fv01-OI"))  ###character path = ‘1998/001/19980101-EUR-L4-SPIM-ATL-v01-fv01-OI.nc’ 
{ list_fichier_short <-r_a_traiter }   
FUllList <- c(FUllList, FileList)  
} 

str(FUllList)#7301`
```

Comment: do you have an example BZIP file you can share?