# how to install tinytex from local zip file in R

Tags: r, tinytex

I have just installed the `tinxytex` package in R

`install.packages('tinytex')`

I would like to run the following code to install actual *TinyTeX*

`tinytex::install_tinytex()`

This leads to the below **error**: (As I am behind a proxy etc.)

> In download.file(url, output, ..., method = method) :
>     cannot open URL 'http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl.zip': HTTP status was '403 Forbidden' ```

As a work around I downloaded the `install-tl.zip` file in my browser and was wondering if there is a way when running `tinytex::install_tinytex()` to point to this `.zip` file ?

For example something like:

`tinytex::install_tinytex(repository = "\\Downloads\\")`

Howevever this leads to the below error:

> In download.file(url, output, ..., method = method) :
>     URL 'http://Downloads/install-tl.zip': status was 'URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

**Environment**

- `R 3.5.3`

Comment: Do you have permissions to write in the directory you're working on?

Comment: Yes operating in my username c drive

Comment: It seems that you don't have [permission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) to download anything.

Comment: Yeah that's why I have the zip file locally which I would like to install from via `install_tinytex` just no idea how :)

Comment: You can try with `unzip`, although I never tried install a software directly wtih `unzip` before. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203800/unzip-a-zip-file) can be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To install `tinytex` in an offline manner, you could

1. Download the prebuilt version of TinyTex from appveyor CI [TinyTeX.zip](https://ci.appveyor.com/api/projects/yihui/tinytex/artifacts/TinyTeX.zip)
2. Use `tinytex:::install_windows_zip()` on this file

This should work.

This comes from how `tinytex:::install_prebuilt()` is working. (see [source](https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/blob/b54b5889eac8c4be8bfb0139f0ba645a29cafee9/R/install.R#L308))