# how can i decompress this file from c#

Tags: c#, r

The file was compressed in c# with this code:

```cs
using (FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream("myfile.gff", FileMode.Create))
{
    using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
    {
        ZipArchiveEntry write_entry = archive.CreateEntry(GRALflowfield);
        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(write_entry.Open()))
        {
          //writing 
        }
    }
 }
```

I know how to read binary in R, but i don't know which decompression should i use.
I know that .gff is not important.
I tried this, but it gives error back: error 1 in extracting from zip

```
zipF <- file.choose()
outDir<-paste(getwd(),"/open", sep="")
unzip(zipF , exdir = outDir)
```

Comment: Your C# code is writing a Zip Archive, so your question becomes [How to unzip and archive in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203800/unzip-a-zip-file)

Comment: I tried it,but it gives error back: error 1 in extracting from zip